# Finding evidence of spam emails in database table exp_email_tracker

Tags: email, spam

I started getting some spam messages that appear to be sent by my install of Expression Engine.

The only evidence I am seeing is some database entries in the table
exp_email_tracker

There are not spam user accounts.

I'm confused about both how this could happen and where to start to fix it. Has anyone run into a similar issue?

Currently running EE 2.9.0. With the Snaptcha add on

Comment: my first step has been to upgrade to EE 2.11.3 and update all add ons to the latest EE 2 compatible version, I'm also installing an SSL cert

Comment: What version of EE were you running previously? Have you seen any evidence of spam since upgrading?

Comment: previously EE 2.9.0 - no evidence of spam or any suspicious activity since upgrade - I also blocked the IP on my server's firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I found no evidence of a hacked EE install. Upgrading to the latest EE 2 in my case (2.11.3) seemed to fix the issue. I'll be sure to update if I find anything else.